# How to make a nested loop faster and shorter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I'm building a password hacking program with Python:

python

```
import string

chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits

user_passw = input("enter pass")


for char1 in chars:
    for char2 in chars:
        for char3 in chars:
            for char4 in chars:
                for char5 in chars:
                    if (char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5) == user_passw:
                        print("its " + char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5)
                        exit()
```

How could I make this 5d loop faster or shorter. My goal is to guess a 12 character password and if i make a 12d loop my PC can't handle that or is so slow.

Comment: 1) this isn't a `numpy` question 2) look up `itertools.product`

Comment: @DanielF 1) im so sorry my bad 2) im going to search thanks for answer

Comment: @DanielF its just shorter code not faster

Comment: Yep, brute force is slow.  That's why good passwords are long and complex.  And why good password systems have timeouts and logging.

Comment: Let's do a little math: 12 characters with 62 options is `62**12=3e21`.  Even if your loops took 1e-9s (1 nanosecond, which would be blisteringly fast) you're still looking at 100,000 years to brute force that.

Comment: @DanielF i know math :) i just need faster way ok? if you don't know(or it doesn't exist) you can say that

Comment: It doesn't exist.  You're up against physics, until someone comes up with a quantum computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use itertools:

```python
import itertools
import string

chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits

user_passw = input("Enter Your Password: ")

for password_length in range(1, 9):
    for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=1):
        guess = ''.join(guess)
        if guess == user_passw:                
            print('Password Is {}'.format(guess))
            exit()
```

The first loop tries the brute force for passwords with lengths from 1 to 9.
The second loop tries every combination from chars.